# How can I get my OpenVPN server running OpenBSD 4.3 to authenticate against my Windows domain?

Tags: openvpn, openbsd

I've googled all over the place but none of the pages I have come across include a step-by-step guide showing how to set this up. I'm not a Linux master (although I'm working hard to increase my knowledge of it), and I need to be walked through how to set this up.

I'm aware of things like openldap and what not, but I still need to see each step I need to complete during the entire process which I haven't been able to find.

If anybody can help out I'd greatly appreciate it.

Thanks!

Edit: Sorry, it is OpenBSD 4.3

Comment: You mention BSD, what flavor?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below are my notes for authing OpenVPN off of AD via a RADIUS server. All of the instructions are based on Red Hat. It's been a while since I've done this but from what I remember you do this:

1. Add PAM files

   - cd /location/of/openvpn-x.x._rcx/plugin/auth-pam
   - make
   - sudo cp openvpn-auth-pam.so /etc/openvpn/
   - sudo cp openvpn-auth-pam.so /lib/security
   - Download the pam_radius_auth pam module (will have to edit the .spec file to point to what raddb folder/file and then compile it)
   - cp the new pam_radius_auth module to /lib/security/
2. vi /etc/raddb/server

   - radius_server1_ip     radius_server1_secret
   - radius_server2_ip     radius_server2_secret (if you want redundant servers)
   - Configure what groups you want to be able to access it via AD and the RADIUS setup
3. vi /etc/pam.d/openvpn-auth

   - auth            required        /lib/security/pam_radius_auth.so      debug
   - account         sufficient      /lib/security/pam_permit.so
   - session         sufficient      /lib/security/pam_permit.so
4. Install the PAM modules

   - vi server.conf
   - plugin /etc/openvpn/openvpn-auth-pam.so /etc/pam.d/openvpn-auth

Things may have changed a little bit since I've done it but this should at least get you going in the right direction.

Comment: When did OpenBSD start using PAM?

Comment: Here's direction for the same thing on FreeBSD (not quite the same as OpenBSD, but close): http://blog.hongens.nl/guides/setting-up-openvpn-using-radius-on-freebsd/

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you plan to authenticate based on username and password?

The last time I had to setup something similar I used the *auth-user-pass-verify* option. It tells OpenVPN to pass along the incoming username and password to a custom script, to then grant or deny access based on the return code from the script.

This is a pretty convenient solution, as you generally can expect your scripting language of choice to have a good set of modules for various kinds of authentication. It is also a very flexible solution in defining the authentication criterias.

Assuming that the Windows domain is an Active Directory perhaps you might want to base your script on a simplified Kerberos auth module? After all, the only response you need is a true or a false.

In any case the *auth-user-pass-verify* option is pretty well documentated in the openvpn(8) man page.